# launching ionic2 app from play store causes Application Error: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I am getting the following error when launching my ionic2 application on Android. It presents itself as an alert on the splash screen of the application. This is a production-ready build that I loaded to Google Play Alpha Release and successfully downloaded from the store. I have uploaded many versions of the application to the store successfully; this is the first time that I have experienced this issue. I am not sure why I am experiencing this now. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Application Error
net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
(http://192.168.xx.xxx:xxxx/)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that this was happening was because the  tag in my config.xml had its source attribute changed at some point. I do not know what caused this, but, changing the

```
<content src="http://192.168.xx.xxx:xxxx/"></content>
```

to

```
<content src="index.html"></content>
```

fixed my issue.